# 401(k) loan and job transfer

Tags: united-states, 401k, credit

**Background**

I took a 401(k) loan to facilitate a move across state (My wife is a newly graduated physician who took a residency offer near our new home). I up and switched jobs in the same career field to stay with her, and failed to properly vet the organization I was joining. As such, I am switching companies to one that I have had more time to properly vet and have a discussion with.

We have enough emergency money to cover expenses even if I lose my new job in the first couple weeks of having it. Using the emergency money to cover the outstanding 401(k) loan is not an option, as it would introduce an unacceptable level of risk into our finances. The field I am in has such a desperate lack of qualified workers that I can be assured of a new offer within a week of losing a job (though the company may be unsavory).

**Question**

I am exploring options for mitigating the financial loss that would occur should I default on the outstanding 401(k) loan (~10k USD). I can handle the tax and penalty hit should I need to, but I feel I have other options available.

I can take out an unsecured line of credit for the outstanding balance at a 5.5% APR (credit score over 770 at last report), which will be a significantly reduced cost in the long run, but will up my cash outflow in the short run, thereby increasing risk. I can mitigate that risk by taking an identical 401(k) loan after the new plan allows, thereby seating myself back in the same situation, with a small cost of transaction.

As far as I see, those are the three most prominent options (Take the hit, including taxes; cover the gap with an unsecured line of credit; or use an unsecured line of credit to bridge between 2 401(k) loans) . **I'm not asking for a decision to be made for me, rather, I'd like to cover the pros and cons of each option to minimize my mistakes and risks.** I am relatively inexperienced as far as juggling debt goes. If it matters, the 401(k) account for both companies will be with the same lender on a similar-but-not-identical plan setup.

The answers thus far hit on our unwillingness to pay down debt. To forestall another post point out that debt is a choice (I agree, it is), I will lay out where our income is going.

My wife will not make a doctors salary until she has completed her 4 years of residency. Until then, our household income rests at roughly 120k USD annually (dependent on my overtime). Her student loans cost nearly 4,000 USD monthly, and our only consumer based debt is her car at under 400 USD monthly. We do use a joint credit card, but never beyond what we can pay off that month. Neither of us has ever owed or paid any interest on a credit card. The 401(k) loan in question costs 427 USD monthly; with a mortgage of just under 1,100 USD monthly, that puts the present (not future) cost of the decision to own a house at par with renting an equivalent apartment in the area.

Comment: I'm confused - so you have a 401(k) loan with a company that you've already left, or with the one you're _considering_ leaving?

Comment: @DStanley As of this morning, just left. To clarify, I left Job 1 to move, got to job 2, **then** took out the 401(k) loan, and have just left job 2 to move on to job 3.

Comment: Can you rescind your resignation and hold out until the loan is paid off? That's the _best_ move (financially).

Comment: Due to health concerns, that is not feasible. The position this company put me in is not sustainable. As I mentioned, there is a direct lack of skilled labor in my field, and this company decided to place me in a position well above my capabilities without sufficient support. The stress is resulting in trips to the urgent care (ulcers/insomnia/psychotic episodes). While I could remain, I imagine the eventual health bills will be far more expensive than the tax penalty.

Comment: Is job 3 already lined up? Do you know that it has a 401(k) plan, it accepts incoming rollovers, it allows loans, it doesn't have a long waiting period to join the plan?

Comment: @stannius job number 3 is a choice between 2 jobs with similar pay and benefits, both using the same 401(k) company as job number 2. Waiting period is 30 days. payback for 401(k) loans are marked at 60 days after end of employment.

Comment: Is the house a done deal?

Comment: Have you looked into credit card with introductory 0% interest? With a good credit score and a six-figure income, you should have a decent chance at getting one.

Comment: The reason I ask is, if you're only going to be in an area for four years, renting is probably better than buying.

Comment: Why is an unsecured line of credit at 5.5% higher risk? Either way you are paying a loan payment every month. At only 5.5% interest, and not being secured by your 401(k) / related to keeping your job, the personal loan seems way lower risk. Is the term short?

Comment: house is purchased, a sale would be close to par though, due to the lack of inventory in the market. 5.5% interest on an unsecured is higher than 4.25% paid back into the 401(k). The loan terms require you to pay interest into the 401(k) post-tax, and the only non-future cost is a small admin fee. With the way the market is going, I haven't lost any future interest either, as my 401(k) ROI is below 0% since I took the loan. 4.25% won't keep up with the market long term though, even if it's not volatile.

Comment: I want to stress, the fact that it has worked out this far does not mean I made a good decision taking out the 401(k) loan, it just means I got lucky.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would NOT "take the hit" and pay the taxes and penalty unless you had no other choice. That's effectively paying ~35% "interest" on the loan. The best *financial* decision is to use all but 1-2K of the emergency fund to pay off the 401(k) loan, then save like mad to build it back up. I would also not take out *another* 401(k) loan. Remember that with a 401(k) loan, the *true* cost is the *opportunity cost* of not having your money invested in the market, which can be upwards of 10-20% in bull markets. Plus as you know, if you leave your job, the loan is due in full, which can leave you in tight spots like you are in now.

Yes, using your emergency fund increases risk from the standpoint of not having a large emergency fund in cash, but with a decent credit score you can always borrow money later if you *need* to, or find other ways to deal with the emergency.

Finally, I would look at *why* you felt like you needed a loan in the first place. I get the sense that you've acted somewhat impulsively in the past, borrowing money to fund your actions without a real plan of paying it back or knowing what the true cost is. If this is a pattern that will continue, then that's fine, but I would build an even *larger* emergency fund to finance these decisions, rather then borrowing money and not having to deal with the consequences until later.

Comment: I understand and agree with the 401(k) loan being a huge cost in the future. The reason we decided it was the best course of action was our decision to switch from renting to owning. The housing market in our area had such a lack of inventory that even apartments were going for ~$1500 monthly per bedroom. The 401(k) loan was the only loan that flew under the radar as far as mortgage underwriting is concerned.

It did not help that, despite planning for extra housing expenses, we only had ~3 months total after finding out what city we were moving to for securing housing.

Comment: Upvoted despite our disagreement in recommendation.  However we both understand the core issue.

Comment: @GOATNine Can you find cheaper apartments in an area that's farther away? I really think you need to get these finances in order before buying a house or you'll just keep chasing bad decisions by making more bad decisions. I understand that things aren't perfect right now but perhaps some pain and sacrifice in the short term will get you out of this hole.

Comment: @DStanley I'm not looking for perfect. The area we are in is just that expensive. Apparently the population growth is on the order of 35-45 people daily here. The way residency works is on a match system, similar to if you were given exactly 1 job offer and told to take it or leave it. She could not have chosen a different location if she wanted to (this was her #1 location by ranking).

Comment: I'm not saying _she_ should choose a different location. Can she have the same job but you rent an apartment 20-30 minutes farther way and save a few hundred dollars a month?

Comment: @DStanley now that we're in the area, that's a good point. I'm looking through to see if I can find something. 20-30 minutes wouldn't put undue strain on her (I hope) as she's working over 100h weekly right now.

Comment: 30 minutes extra commute (per person!) for "a few hundred dollars" doesn't strike me as a good idea. Pertinent: http://www.mrmoneymustache.com/2011/10/06/the-true-cost-of-commuting/ -- keep in mind that money and time you put into your car is sunk down the drain, whereas money and time you put into your home with a better location is building equity.

Comment: @GOATNine 20-30 mins more times 2 is a lot of time. I currently lose 2,5hrs a day to commuting and I hate it. I'd rather work that time.

Comment: @DonQuiKong I'm not saying forever. I'm saying for a year or so until some of this mess is cleaned up.

Comment: I'll Cost-Benefit-Analysis some nearby rentals to check, but in general the extra time driving does kill any benefit. It's more about what kind of cash flow changes you see by moving (basically putting the cost forward by moving it onto the car maintenance rather than paying it immediately).

Comment: @GOATNine Current cash flow is your problem, which is what you should focus on. Adding a few hundred miles a month to your car is not going to kill you in the long run, but not having cash to pay off debt can kill you in the short run if it causes you to make unwise financial decisions.

Comment: @DStanley driving 30 minutes after a 14 hour shift very well might literally kill OP's spouse.

Comment: And even if it doesn't, it might be the difference between burn out and surviving that year. Sure, a few extra hours in the car doesn't sound like a lot. But it is. It's back pain and getting up another 10 mins earlier to make a coffee so you don't fall asleep in the car and it's trading the last few hours of free time against commuting. It's like taking the counterweight from the balance and adding it to the other side.  It's not worth a few hundred bucks. Hell, if I got op right, she's becoming a doctor next year. Screw that money. You'll be fine. Do your best, but don't risk everything.

Comment: @DonQuiKong "4 years of residency". The OP is in a mess. There's no room for "convenience" at this point. They need to clean up the mess first (which means cutting expenses to the minimum) , _then_ they have more margin to address conveniences. Borrowing more money to pay back debt is an endless cycle.

Comment: @DStanley just to clear the air, we are in no way anywhere near insolvent. A mess may be an accurate assessment of the situation, but we still have a net inflow of cash, and I retain the ability to earn more with just more work. Even the job transfer has sound financial reasoning behind it: I'm migrating from Salary to Hourly for a better rate, with the same schedule of hours, and a third of the commute. I didn't just bail because I don't like my job, I stuck around until I found something better. that being said, you are as always a font of good advice.

Answer (score 10):

There is another option (which is the one I would choose):

Establish a line of credit.  This will cost a small administration fee, but if you don't *use* the line of credit it won't cost any interest.  Use your emergency money to pay off the loan, and then, if it turns out that you needed the emergency money, use the line of credit.  (Do it this way, so that you can still draw on the line of credit, even if you have both lost your jobs - when the unsecured loan might not be available.)

Comment: Ideally, this is what the unsecured personal loan would be. My preferred banking institution doesn't hand out unsecured lines of credit though, hence the loan terminology.

Comment: Can you not get a credit card *anywhere else*?

Comment: Credit cards are different from lines of credit in that they can be withdrawn from (like taking out credit as cash). I have no desire to get another credit card, and it would not do anything in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not asking for a decision to be made for me, rather, I'd like to cover the pros and cons of each option to minimize my mistakes and risks.

This question is very much situation and personal dependent.  What will your wife's new income be?  How much student loan and other consumer debt are you carrying?  Will your new area offer better salary opportunity or worse for you?  Will you two live the "doctor lifestyle" now, or live well below your means to get debt paid off?

All of those things changes the calculus of risk versus cost.

However from your post I am assuming that it is your intent to now live the doctor lifestyle and not work on debt.  I assume this because you are talking about defaulting on a 10k loan that needs to be paid back in about 6 months.  I am assuming your household income is at least 150K/year.

The answer to this question, like many others in personal finance, comes down to one of behavior not math.  You two are fully capable of paying down this loan in two months, let alone the 6 months that you actually have.  It will be a matter of cutting your spending, getting on a written budget, and earning as much as possible.  That 401K loan will be paid off in no time, and then you can work on other consumer debt.

If you two are not interested in doing that, I would recommend to "default" or pay the taxes on the 401K loan.  It is highly inefficient cost wise, but as you said it reduces risk. You two will probably be giving such a large portion of your future income to banks the current costs really don't matter much.

Comment: For the next 4 years, the majority of our income will be going to her student debt. We will not be living the "doctor lifestyle". Even our decision to purchase a home as opposed to renting was due to the monthly cost rather than the desire to own. Neither of us has paid a penny of credit card interest ever, and our consumer debt is near 0 (her car being the only exception). Her student loans cost us slightly under 4,000 USD monthly, which is where the bulk of our expenses lie. After 4 years, she will be making a physicians salary, until then, we are under 120k household.

Comment: @GOATNine can't you defer student loans in residency?  If so there is your solution.  Defer for 2.5 months, use that 4k to pay off the 401K loan, then go back to the loans.

Comment: The decision to defer is either for the duration, or not at all. It would also involve 60,000 USD interest capitalizing on the loans. I'd rather take the tax hit. I triple checked to make sure there wasn't an income based option or similar. I make too much for her to qualify, but not enough to seat us comfortably. We also looked at me quitting, and the finances didn't look too hot with that either.

Comment: You can still make payments on deferred loans.  If you are worried about risk that is a great option.

Comment: @GOATNine If any of the loans are subsidized, then they won't accrue interest in deferment, and after 2.5 months of paying off the 401k loan you can resume normal payments (or bump them up if possible). Deferment is the best option imo, unless the loan rates are crazy high.

Comment: We can absolutely do that, but the interest will capitalize immediately from the past 8 years worth of accrual. That's the 60,000 USD I was referring to. Plus, the 401(k) loan will default after 60 days. default on 2,000 USD is better than on 10,000 USD, but likely not worth the additional costs.

Comment: @GOATNine are you saying that if your wife chooses to defer her loans, $60k will instantly be added to the balance? And that $60k wouldn't be added if she didn't choose to defer?

Comment: @stannous yes, because those loans are from before medical school, but they're managed under the same program.

Comment: @GOATNine That's rather odd. Retroactively charging interest is something that furniture stores do, not student loan lenders. (Student loans have their own problems, especially private ones, but I've never heard of that particular aspect on a student loan.) That said, I am no student loan expert.

Comment: @stannous it's possible I misunderstood the agent we called to schedule our payments. I know switching from income-based to non-income-based also causes interest to capitalize. At least on Direct PLUS loans

Comment: @GOATNine from your comments above you guys are in a hot mess and need to stop borrowing ASAP.  You seem to take pride in not having paid a dime in CC interest, but I am not sure how your situation is any better than those that have.

Comment: @PeteB. This is literally the first time we've hit a snag, and it was from misinformation, not from poor planning. Had we been lead honestly about her loans, we would not have an issue. As it is, the planning we had done to keep ourselves financially sound let us take on nearly 3,000 USD a month more than we anticipated. I appreciate that you're dealing with a "fix it for me" crowd on SE every day, but as I stated, that is not me. I just want to be sure I'm not missing anything critical.

Comment: If your wife is like my doctor, she will still have student loan debt 20 years after she has established her own practice. Malpractice insurance and cost of running a practice eat up a lot of the intake.

Comment: @GOATNine it does seem after some reading that it is at least possible that some actions you may take do capitalize the interest. It's not really adding $60k to your debt; that $60k is already money your wife owes. But it would make that $60k included in the interest calculations going forward, which is indeed a big deal, and quite possibly would cost you more than paying the taxes and penalty on a defaulted 401(k) loan. That said, it depends on when the interest would have capitalized otherwise, which it is going to do sooner or later.

Comment: @stannius exactly, the world of finance and student loans is complicated. I'm just smart enough to know that I know next to nothing about it.

Comment: Depending on your wife's future doctor income, 10% + taxes now might be cheaper than just taxes later. That said, you have to come up with the money now.

Answer (score -1):

I want to note that it is not necessarily have an early withdrawal penalty if you default on your 401(k) loan. Although a default on your 401(k) loan is treated as a withdrawal, it will not be considered a withdrawal if you "rollover" the "withdrawal" into an IRA or to a new 401(k) plan; i.e. if you deposit the amount of the 401(k) loan you defaulted on into an IRA or your new company's 401(k). Normally, you can only make this "rollover" contribution to the IRA within 60 days of the "withdrawal" (unless the government grants you a hardship exception). However, in the 2018 and later tax years, in the case where the loan default was caused by you leaving work, you have until the tax filing deadline, including extensions (October 15 of the following year, if you have an extension; April 15 if you don't have an extension), to make this rollover.

This is described in Publication 590-A, section [Time Limit for Making a Rollover Contribution](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590a#en_US_2017_publink1000230578):

> For distributions made in tax years beginning after December 31, 2017,
>   you have until the due date (including extensions) for your tax return
>   for the tax year in which the offset occurs to roll over a qualified
>   plan loan offset amount. A “qualified plan loan offset amount” is the
>   amount your employer plan account balance is reduced, or offset, to
>   repay a loan from the plan. The offset must be because either the plan
>   terminated or you severed your employment with the employer.

So I would suggest you wait until early next year to see how much cash you have at that time to contribute to this rollover, and only if you still don't have enough money to cover the loan default at that time, do you consider your options above.

Comment: To avoid the loan being considered an early withdrawal, it will need to be paid in full by Jan 2, 2019. Any amount not repaid by that date will be taxed at our joint income and subject to a 10% penalty. It's interesting to note that the rollover option exists though.

Comment: @GOATNine: "Any amount not repaid by that date will be taxed at our joint income and subject to a 10% penalty." Again, that is not true. You probably got that from the 401k plan saying how much time you have to repay the loan or default. But as I explained above, defaulting on the loan does not mean it will lead to any tax or penalty -- if you rollover the "loan offset" into an IRA or another 401k before the tax filing deadline, including extensions, it is not an "early withdrawal", and there is no tax or penalty.

Comment: There is something missing, or it would be standard practice to "rollover" already spent funds into an IRA to avoid the payback period. If I roll from 401(k) distribution to a traditional IRA, I have the same 10% penalty issue. If I roll into a ROTH, I owe taxes on the sum. I can't roll over money that isn't currently in the account though. I would have had to do that first, then disburse the sum. I would still owe the taxes, even if not the penalty.

Comment: @GOATNine: "There is something missing, or it would be standard practice to "rollover" already spent funds into an IRA to avoid the payback period." Well, normally, a rollover must be done within 60 days of the distribution, so it isn't much of an additional period. This is the same for loan defaults prior to 2018. It is a new thing in 2018 that loan defaults due to leaving job have a much longer period to rollover, so maybe this isn't "standard practice" yet.

Comment: @GOATNine: "I can't roll over money that isn't currently in the account though." As long as you have a distribution, and you make a rollover contribution within the required period, it counts as a "rollover", and the distribution does not have tax or penalty. The fact that you default on a 401k loan makes it a distribution. All you need to do is make a rollover contribution within the required period of time. You do not need to indicate when you make a distribution that you will roll it over to something else. You just need to indicate that it's a rollover contribution when you put it back.

Comment: @GOATNine: If it's pre-tax funds in a Traditional 401k, you should roll it over to a Traditional IRA (also sometimes called "Rollover IRA" in some IRA managers), not Roth IRA. A conversion to Roth is taxable.

Comment: You should provide a link I can reference. I believe you, and I would 100% take advantage of this if I can, but I can't seem to find any literature on the subject whatsoever, even with regards to political pundits describing/complaining about it.

Comment: @GOATNine: I can cite the section of law that provides for it, in IRC 402(c)(3)(C), but if you want a simple description, you can google for "extended rollover period for plan loan offset amounts" and you will find plenty of links, from both official and third-party sources.

Comment: According to https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/rollovers-of-retirement-plan-and-ira-distributions a loan treated as a distribution (which is what happens when it defaults) is NOT eligible to roll over.

Comment: @BenVoigt: What they call "loans treated as a distribution" is not what we are describing here (which is actually a loan offset that is treated as a distribution). If you click on the "loans" link, it specifically says in section "Loans to an employee that leaves the company" that for a person leaving the company unable to repay the loan, the employer will treat it as a distribution, and the employee can avoid tax consequences by rolling it over to an IRA. The "loan treated as a distribution" is the type described in the following section "Loans that do not meet legal requirements".

Comment: @BenVoigt: The restrictions for rollovers from 401(k) is stated more clearly in Publication 575, section [Eligible rollover distribution](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p575#en_US_2017_publink1000226896), where one of the disallowed situations is "A loan treated as a distribution because it doesn't satisfy certain requirements..."

Comment: @user102008: Strange, because your comment says "The fact that you default on a 401k loan makes it a distribution".  But it is not the loan amount that is distributed, but the funds sold from the account to pay the balance due?  Does this apply in every default situation, or only when payment of the loan is accelerated?

Comment: @BenVoigt: The funds corresponding to the amount of the loan were already sold from investments in your 401(k) account when you took out the loan, in order to "loan" you that cash. There is no distribution there. You were supposed to pay the entire remaining loan balance back to your 401(k) immediately upon leaving the company, but you didn't pay some or all of it, and the missing portion is a default, which counts as a distribution (even though you didn't actually receive any money at the time of the default). That fake "distribution" can be rolled over into an IRA.